# How to add paypal basket?

Tags: paypal

I have been playing around with website design again recently, currently at a stage where I want to implement PayPal fully. Having read PayPal's documentation I have so far been able to add buttons (buy now for singular product x quantity, or add to basket).

The website is all raw HTML/CSS with no CMS system like WordPress etc.

I have been trying to understand the PayPal API to stop 'View My Basket' taking customers away from the website, also from a customer point of view, I would rather customers not have to be redirected every time they want to check baskets.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Basket" functionality is implemented by *shopping cart* software, which is similar to a CMS. (There is some overlap, for example you mention the Wordpress CMS which has a popular shopping cart called 'WooCommerce' available).  PayPal has a number of [official partners](https://www.paypal.com/us/business/platforms-and-marketplaces/directory/custom-online-stores) that offer cart functionality, but really most ecommerce software works with PayPal anyway, so you're basically spoiled for choice. You could also write your own custom shopping cart, which is of course more work.